# Publish method leaking data to incorrect client

Tags: meteor

Is there something obviously wrong with my publish function?

The behaviour I am seeing is that when two clients are both subscribing to this, it seems that they *both* get the 'latest' set of results (most recent subscribe request). This means that a client is getting leaked data from a different subscribe request.

Much appreciated!

John

```
Meteor.publish('myFiles', function () {

  var regexUser = '';
  var user = '';

  if (this.userId) {
    user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
  } else {
    user='';
  }

  if (user && user.profile && user.profile.folder) {

    var query = {key: {$in: [/^Team files\//i, new RegExp('^' + user.profile.folder)]}};

    return MyFiles.find(query);

  } else {

    return MyFiles.find({
      key: {
        $in: [/^Team files\//i]
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Update: I have made it work correctly, but I cannot see any reason for the alternate approach to work!

```
  if (this.userId && Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).profile && Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).profile.folder)

  return MyFiles.find({
    $or: [
  {key: new RegExp('^' + Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).profile.folder + '/')}, {key: new RegExp('^' + 'Team files/')}]
  });
```

Comment: Does client A receive "leaked" files when the client B subscribes, or does it happen even without client B subscribing?

Comment: The example I can replicate easily is... A subscribes and can see A's files. When B then subscribes, B sees A's files. Resubscribing as B has the same effect - the files returned by the publish query are correct, but the client sees the results as if subscribing as A. Driving me crazy ha ha!